# Proving the open disc is not compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Prove that the open disc $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2<1\}$ considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

I can find the following covering of the disc $B_{1-\frac{1}{n}}(0,0):n\in\mathbb{N}$.

$D\subseteq\bigcup_\limits{i=1}^{\infty}B_{1-\frac{1}{n}}(0,0)$.

This covering is infinite and there is no finite sub covering then $D$ is not compact.

**Question:**

Is this right? If not. What should I do to prove $D$ is not compact?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Take this note to your hand. A disc is in that case not a subspace but a subset

Comment: @Fakemistake              It is not me that said that but the book.

Comment: @Fakemistake The information that $D$ is a **subspace** of $\mathbb{R}^2$ is essential because it tells us which topology on the set $D$ is considered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. But you  have to show,  that each collection of finitely many of your discs do not cover the set $D $.

Comment: I am going to complete the proof in the present comment for you to check if this is right.

Comment: If there was a finite subcover then $\exists m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}B_{1-\frac{1}{n}}(0,0)\supseteq D$ However if  $\bigcup_{i=1}^{m}B_{1-\frac{1}{n}}(0,0)=B_{1-\frac{1}{m}}(0,0)$ If $x\in B_{1-\frac{1}{m}}(0,0)$ then $d(x,0)<1-\frac{1}{m}<1$ which implies $D\supseteq B_{1-\frac{1}{m}}(0,0)$

Comment: Now your proof is fine!

Comment: I disagree that this proof is fine. It should be shown that $D\not\subset B_{1-\frac{1}{m}}(0,0)$ but you showed that $B_{1-\frac{1}{m}}(0,0)\subseteq D$ which is not the same.

Answer (score 3):

In $\mathbb{R}^2$,  a compact set is closed and bounded...

Here, the set $D$ is not closed.

Answer (score 2):

You should show that $$D\not\subset B_{1-\frac{1}{m}}(0,0)$$

Therfore you should show that there is some $(x,y)\in D$ where $(x,y)\notin B_{1-\frac{1}{m}}(0,0)$.

For that you might just choose $(x,y)=(1-\frac{1}{m},0)$.

---

*alternatively*

Use the theorem of *Heine and Borel* (sometimes referred to as *Borel and Lebesgue*) which says that in Euclidean space $\mathbb{R}^n$ the **compact** subsets are identical to the ones that are **closed and bounded**.